# CMake - customize 'make help' output

Tags: cmake

I introduced CMake to my project it replaced Make's makefiles. Anyhow I'm not able to find how to customize 'make help' output. This target is created automagically anyhow I would like to add some descriptions for particular targets. It is anyhow possible?

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting `help` with `add_custom_target` results in:

```
See also "/tmp/20/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (add_custom_target):
  The target name "help" is reserved or not valid for certain CMake features,
  such as generator expressions, and may result in undefined behavior.
```

Instead of overwriting what cmake generates, write your own `make` wrapper one directory above the cmake one. Like so:

```
$ cd /your/project
$ ls
_build    CMakeLists.txt    source_file.c    Makefile
$ cmake -S. -B./_build
... configure the project in ./_build builddir ...
$ make
cmake --build _build --target all
<builds the project>
$ make help
This is your help
```

With `Makefile`:

```
all:
    cmake --build _build --target all
configure_for_some_configuration:
    cmake -S. -B_build -DSOME_OPTION=true
help:
    @echo 'This is your help'
.PHONY: help configure_for_some_configuration all
```

Remember that `make` is **one of** several of supported generators. I recommend `Ninja` for faster builds. Use `cmake --build <the build dir>` to abstractly build the project independently of the used generator.